# Solving for $r$, possibly using Newton's method or the Lambert $W$ function?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, newton-raphson, lambert-w

Consider the equation

$$K=\frac{gR_{0}\left(r+1\right)^{t}\left(\left(w+1\right)^{N}-\left(r+1\right)^{N}\right)}{\ln\left(w+1\right)-\ln\left(r+1\right)},$$

such that $g,R_0,r,w\in \mathbb{R}$ and $N\in\mathbb{R}^+$. Can this be solved for $r$? Any help would be much appreciated.

For background, the above is a solution to the differential equation

$$S\cdot\frac{dP}{dt}=\frac{I\left(t+N\right)}{S\left(1+w\right)^{t+N}}-\frac{I\left(t\right)}{S\left(1+w\right)^{t}}$$

where $I(t):=\left(1-\tau\right)\left(gR_0(1+r)^t-J\right)$ and the constant $K=\frac{SP+C}{\left(1-T\right)\left(i+1\right)^{-N-t}}-\frac{J\left(1-\left(i+1\right)^{N}\right)}{\ln\left(i+1\right)}$.

Comment: From a practical point of view, how does $r$ compare to $w$ ? Larger, much larger ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$x=\left(\frac{r+1}{w+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{t}} \qquad \text{and} \qquad A=\frac{K }{g R_0 t(w+1)^{N+t}}\qquad \text{and} \qquad a=\frac N t$$ and the equation becomes
$$A \log(x)= x(x^a-1)$$ If $x\gg 1$, then we have (as an *approximation*)
$$x\sim \Bigg[-\frac{A }{1+a}W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1+a}{A}\right)\Bigg]^{\frac 1{1+a}}$$ from which you could start Newton method.

Suppose $t=N=A=10$ , this would give $x=3.56556$  and Newton iterates will be

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 3.56556 \\
 1 & 4.63742 \\
 2 & 4.38790 \\
 3 & 4.37384 \\
 4 & 4.37380
\end{array}
\right)$$

For the case where $t=0$, let

$$x=\left(\frac{r+1}{w+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}} \qquad \text{and} \qquad A=\frac K{g R_0 N(w+1)^N}$$ which makes
$$A \log(x)=x-1 \implies x=-A\, W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{A}e^{-1/A}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for this. For your original question, $r$ can be less than $w$ (or even negative). Also, what is the error term for the approximation (i.e. in big $\mathcal{O}$ notation)?

Comment: @UNOwen. Answer updated (for better, I hope).

Comment: Yes, much better :)

Answer (score 2):

Lambert W doesn't seem to help on this one.  Newton's method will work, but it will produce numerical solutions (for given values of the constants) rather than symbolic solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If $t=0$, could a solution be expressed symbolically?

Comment: Yes, see Claude Leibovici's answer.